# String triangle with space as delimiter C language

Tags: c, string, space, delimiter

This is a unique triangle and is different from all other triangles in this way that it prints words separated by spaces.The answers i'm looking for are not there in any other question i've already checked.

the output should look like this

this
this is
this is the
 this is the best
 this is the best way
 this is the best way to
 this is the best way to spend
 this is the best way to spend time

so far the code i have is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char msg[]="this is the best way to spend time for reedaf";
    int inn=1, out, i=0, max;
    max=(sizeof(msg)/sizeof(int))+1;
    char *output;
    char *spc=" ";
      output=strtok(msg,spc);
    for(out=1;out<max;out++){

        for(i=0;i<out && output != NULL ;i++){

      printf("%s ", output);
      output=strtok(NULL,spc);

          }

    printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

this generates this output

this
is the
best way to
spend time for reedaf

so please help me i cant find peace of mind

i need to start each line with the starting word in the array. then the next line should start with the starting word in the array then the next word. then the next line should again start with the starting word in the array then the next word and then the next word.and so on and so forth.

PLEASE TRY NOT TO USE break; OR memcpy

Comment: would you format your code properly and care to explain what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's use of `strtok()` does not restore the string as needed, but simply marches down the string.

Follows is a candidate simplification.

```
void printTri(char *s) {
  for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
    if (s[i] == ' ') {
      s[i] = '\0';
      puts(s);
      s[i] = ' ';
    }
  }
  puts(s);
}

int main(void) {
  char msg[] = "this is the best way to spend time for reedaf";
  printTri(msg);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou sir, only i see that you have to remove size_t thats all and the code works perfectly.

Comment: oh yeah, and you have to declare the i variable too

Comment: you have to remove size_t and declare the"i" variable just before the first for loop and the code works thanks

Comment: @deeraf C99 and later allow a variable to be declare in the `for` loop as above.  You may be using a compiler that is not up=to=date. `size_t` is in `<stddef.h>` and IMO is better to use than `int`, especially for portable routines and when `i` might get _large_.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure about what you have done in your code, But the output you asked for can be obtained by this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char str[]="this is the best way to spend time for reedaf",ch=' ',c='$';
int n=0,x,i,j;
x=strlen(str);
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    if(str[i]==ch)
        n++;
}
for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<x;j++)
    {
        if(str[j]==ch)
        {
            str[j]=c;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(str[j]==c)
                printf("%c",ch);
            else
                printf("%c",str[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You used `break` and for some reason the OP does not like that.

Comment: thanks but could you do this without using break; ? please please please

Comment: @deeraf if you really want it without break statement, then use null character,instead of the dollar sign.Hope that might work.